# How can i delete all files and directories on a USB stick

Tags: linux, shell, rm

I use the c shell.

I wish to remove all the files and directories from a USB stick

There are a lot of files and directories. Many of the files and directories start with a period (I.e. they are so-called hidden files and directories.)

Firstly I `cd` to the stick's mount point. Then the problem is how to
use the rm command.

If I run `rm -r *` I do not delete the hidden files or hidden directories.

If I run `rm -r *.*` I run into problems with `.` (current directory) and `..` (parent directory)

How can I run rm to delete all files and directories (including the
hidden files and directories)?

Answer (score 0):

Your `rm` [refuses to process `.`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/369530/108618). This does not mean it cannot process the directory. It refuses to process the directory *referred to as `.`*.

You can use another name, the "real" name. It can be like `../real_name`, or obtained by expanding `$PWD`:

```
rm -r "$PWD"
```

In your case the directory is a mountpoint. Expect `device or resource busy` when `rm` tries to remove the mountpoint itself. The exit status will not be `0`, still the contents should be removed (assuming sufficient permissions).

Answer (score 0):

The surest way to get rid of everything is just to reformat the stick.

This way you do not have to deal with file and folder permissions
and attributes - you just nuke everything.

Reformat could also improve slightly the speed of the stick,
when starting with everything truly empty.